# PowerShell: Add Users to AD and Add them in Groups

Tags: powershell

I have script which is working fine, which creates a new Active Directory user. I need to modify the script to add the user to their security group.

Here is what the contents of my CSV file look like:

```
Firstname,Lastname,Password,Sam,Group
Alice,Gadbois,azerty+123,a.gadbois,GG1
Quincy,Lagueux,azerty+123,q.lagueux,GG1
```

and here is my PowerShell script:

```
$objOU = [ADSI]"LDAP://OU=TestOU,DC=Domain,DC=local";
$dataSource = import-csv -Path "c:\users.csv";

foreach($dataRecord in $datasource) {
    $cn = $dataRecord.FirstName + " " + $dataRecord.LastName
    $sAMAccountName = $dataRecord.Sam
    $givenName = $dataRecord.FirstName
    $Password = $dataRecord.Password
    $sn = $dataRecord.LastName
    $sAMAccountName = $sAMAccountName.ToLower()    
    $displayName = $sn + ", " + $givenName   
    $userPrincipalName = $sAMAccountName + “@domain.local"    
    $objUser = $objOU.Create("user","CN="+$cn)    
    $objUser.Put("sAMAccountName",$sAMAccountName)
    $objUser.Put("userPrincipalName",$userPrincipalName)    
    $objUser.Put("displayName",$displayName)    
    $objUser.Put("givenName",$givenName)    
    $objUser.Put("sn",$sn)    
    $objUser.SetInfo()
    $objUser.psbase.InvokeSet(“AccountDisabled",$false)
    $objUser.SetInfo()
}
```

I need to add a new command in the script, to add each user to his group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

As Trevor said, you need to import the Active Directory module at the top of your script.

```
Import-module ActiveDirectory
```

And then within your foreach loop, you can add the Add-ADGroupMember Command.

```
foreach($dataRecord in $datasource) {
    $cn = $dataRecord.FirstName + " " + $dataRecord.LastName
    $sAMAccountName = $dataRecord.Sam
    $givenName = $dataRecord.FirstName
    $Password = $dataRecord.Password
    $sn = $dataRecord.LastName
    $sAMAccountName = $sAMAccountName.ToLower()    
    $displayName = $sn + ", " + $givenName   
    $userPrincipalName = $sAMAccountName + “@domain.local"    
    $objUser = $objOU.Create("user","CN="+$cn)    
    $objUser.Put("sAMAccountName",$sAMAccountName)
    $objUser.Put("userPrincipalName",$userPrincipalName)    
    $objUser.Put("displayName",$displayName)    
    $objUser.Put("givenName",$givenName)    
    $objUser.Put("sn",$sn)    
    $objUser.SetInfo()
    $objUser.psbase.InvokeSet(“AccountDisabled",$false)
    $objUser.SetInfo()

    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $dataRecord.Group -Member $sAMAccountName
}
```

Troubleshooting

Verify that each user has group properly assigned:

```
$users = Import-Csv "Path_To_File.csv"
$users | % {
    $_.Group
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesnt work it add user to group, i need to add group to user.
The Cmdles you gave me right now if i use it i will add the same group to all users in my CSV file.

Comment: websch01ar are You there ?

Comment: My apologies. To make it easier, I have updated my post.

Comment: Users are there bu there only members of one groups which is domain users.

I need them to be add into diferent groups which are in the csv file.

Thanks

Comment: Can you look at the data in the CSV file?  You are iterating over each record so $dataRecord.Group is distinct for each row.  However, if each row has the same value, then it will be the same.

Comment: Here is my users.csv file 
Firstname,Lastname,Password,Sam,Group
Alice,Gadbois,azerty+123,a.gadbois,GG1
Quincy,Lagueux,azerty+123,q.lagueux,GG2

Comment: The problem is there is no group assigned at all when i use the script.

Comment: Did you import the ActiveDirectory module?

Comment: Yes
Import-module ActiveDirectory

Comment: How about this, add a write-host $dataRecord.Group so you can see in the shell the value of each row's group.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean, can you explain ?

Comment: I added a troubleshooting query to the answer.  Run that and let me know if you see the right values.  

When you execute Add-ADGroupMember, are you getting an error?

Comment: is there any cmdls that make the powershell still open in order to see ERROS .?

Comment: Copy your script and paste it into a PowerShell window.

Comment: Too many ERRORS do you have email or something where i can contact you ?

Comment: websch01ar~@~gmail..com (remove the ~ character)

Comment: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:7 char:46
+     $sAMAccountName = $sAMAccountName.ToLower <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (ToLower:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Comment: The following exception occurred while retrieving member "Create": "A referral was returned from the server.
"
At line:10 char:15
+     $objUser = <<<<  $objOU.Create("user","CN="+$cn)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ExtendedTypeSystemException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CatchFromBaseGetMember

Comment: What this is saying is $SAMAccountName does not have a value.  So what you need to do is add some defensive code.  I pasted my email above.

Comment: This MS post has a good example of how to leverage the Active Directory module to add a new user.  It will require some changes, but it will be far better!  http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-Create-Active-7e6a3978

Comment: I just sent you 3 messages
1. Errors 2.Script powershell 3.csv file

Answer (score 2):

Use the `ActiveDirectory` PowerShell module that's included with the Remote Server Administration Tools (RSAT). It has a command called `Add-ADGroupMember`.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617210.aspx